# Rails 7 Every File Change Throws Error wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 5)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-7

Have recently setup new Rails 7.0 project with ruby 3.0.3 after booting up the application with bin/dev after changing any file even adding spaces causes this error to occur, below is the log getting

```
19:41:24 web.1  | ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 5)):
19:41:24 web.1  |   
19:41:24 web.1  | activesupport (7.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:62:in `initialize'
19:41:24 web.1  | actionpack (7.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/server_timing.rb:16:in `new'
19:41:24 web.1  | actionpack (7.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/server_timing.rb:16:in `block in call'
19:41:24 web.1  | activesupport (7.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications/fanout.rb:225:in `publish'
19:41:24 web.1  | activesupport (7.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications/fanout.rb:80:in `block in publish'
19:41:24 web.1  | activesupport (7.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications/fanout.rb:91:in `block in iterate_guarding_exceptions'
19:41:24 web.1  | activesupport (7.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications/fanout.rb:90:in `each'
19:41:24 web.1  | activesupport (7.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications/fanout.rb:90:in `iterate_guarding_exceptions'
19:41:24 web.1  | activesupport (7.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications/fanout.rb:80:in `publish'
19:41:24 web.1  | activesupport (7.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:197:in `publish'
19:41:24 web.1  | activeadmin (12ea37a38525) lib/active_admin/application.rb:115:in `load!'
19:41:24 web.1  | activeadmin (12ea37a38525) lib/active_admin/application.rb:228:in `block (2 levels) in attach_reloader'
19:41:24 web.1  | activesupport (7.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:445:in `instance_exec'
19:41:24 web.1  | activesupport (7.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:445:in `block in make_lambda'
19:41:24 web.1  | activesupport (7.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:199:in `block (2 levels) in halting'
19:41:24 web.1  | activesupport (7.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:687:in `block (2 levels) in default_terminator'
19:41:24 web.1  | activesupport (7.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:686:in `catch'
19:41:24 web.1  | activesupport (7.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:686:in `block in default_terminator'
19:41:24 web.1  | activesupport (7.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:200:in `block in halting'
19:41:24 web.1  | activesupport (7.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:595:in `block in invoke_before'
19:41:24 web.1  | activesupport (7.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:595:in `each'
19:41:24 web.1  | activesupport (7.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:595:in `invoke_before'
19:41:24 web.1  | activesupport (7.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:106:in `run_callbacks'
19:41:24 web.1  | activesupport (7.0.0) lib/active_support/reloader.rb:88:in `prepare!'
19:41:24 web.1  | activesupport (7.0.0) lib/active_support/reloader.rb:47:in `block in <class:Reloader>'
19:41:24 web.1  | activesupport (7.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:445:in `instance_exec'
19:41:24 web.1  | activesupport (7.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:445:in `block in make_lambda'
19:41:24 web.1  | activesupport (7.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:271:in `block in simple'
19:41:24 web.1  | activesupport (7.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:599:in `block in invoke_after'
19:41:24 web.1  | activesupport (7.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:599:in `each'
19:41:24 web.1  | activesupport (7.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:599:in `invoke_after'
19:41:24 web.1  | activesupport (7.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:108:in `run_callbacks'
19:41:24 web.1  | activesupport (7.0.0) lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:133:in `run'
19:41:24 web.1  | activesupport (7.0.0) lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:129:in `run!'
19:41:24 web.1  | activesupport (7.0.0) lib/active_support/reloader.rb:114:in `run!'
19:41:24 web.1  | activesupport (7.0.0) lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:74:in `block in run!'
19:41:24 web.1  | <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
19:41:24 web.1  | activesupport (7.0.0) lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:71:in `run!'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating your project without Active Admin. It doesn't seem to support Rails 7 yet. https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/7196

Answer (score 1):

As a temporary solution you can disable `server_timing` in *config/environments/development.rb*:

```
   # Enable server timing
-  config.server_timing = true
+  # config.server_timing = true
```

See https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/7196#issuecomment-1002929616.

---

Thanks @stmpjmpr for the original answer. Just wanted to provide a bit enhanced answer.